# Как соединить словари? \\ Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, словарь, объединение

У меня есть два словаря с разными значениями и ключами.
Как мне из них сделать **один** словарь и в этом словаре будут значения и ключ как с *первого* словаря, так и со *второго*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Работать будет только в Python 3.5 и выше.

```
a = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3} #Создаем словарь a
b = {'d':100, 'e':23, 'f':998} #Создаем словарь b
c = {**a, **b} #Соеденяем словари в переменную c
```

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к ответу от Никита - начиная с Python 3.9, можно использовать [перегруженный оператор `|`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
c = a | b
```

В ответах на [такой же вопрос на англоязычной версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38987/5741205) есть все варианты как для новых так и для старых версий Python

Answer (score 0):

Классический вариант (можно даже соединять словаря при ключах, которые повторяются. При этом "старое значение ключа будет изменено на "новое" ):

```
a = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3} 
b = {'d':100, 'b':2222, 'e':23, 'f':998}
a.update(b)
print(a)
```

Результат:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2222, 'c': 3, 'd': 100, 'e': 23, 'f': 998}
```